# Visual Studio 2010: Is there any function that can create break points at all lines in a .cpp file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, breakpoints

When my friend writes some code I usually don't understand all of it unless I insert break points everywhere and start running the code line by line.

He just send me a .cpp file that has 500 lines in it, which means that I need to click 500 times in order to specify a breakpoint at each line.

Is there any function in the Visual Studio 2010 that can do this job for me?

thanks in advance

Comment: F10, F11, Shift + F11 are your friends, I think?

Comment: Why would you need to insert 500 breakpoints? Why can't you just put them at the points that functions start?

Comment: If any one know please help me. I'm using visual studio 2013 Express (C++ console program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always set 1 breakpoint at the first line of main() and simply use the Step Through option to go through each line or Step Into if it's a function call.